# Entra ID Self Service Signup Application Claim Blade missing in B2X

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, entra

I am using an Entra ID Self Service Signup flow. It works perfectly, but it fails at injecting a custom attribute which is defined but not presented to the user.

I integrated API connectors for federating with an ID provider and for request approval. They are working.

[API connectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z9nj.png)

Now the question:

According to the documentation user attributes, which are collected by the user can be overwritten by the answer of the request endpoint. This works for me. The answer of the API overwrites the collected value from the flow.

If I create a user attribute but do not ask for it in the flow but provide it in the request answer, it is ignored. Is there a way to inject values for user attributes with an API even the user attribute is removed from the signup flow (the extension still exists)?

In the former B2C self signup flows there was a blade called "application claims", where this could be achieved:

[Bad picture, but on the left there you can see "application ..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmELB.png)

The newer Entra ID External Identities is missing this blade:

[Missing Application blades claim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqm27.png)

So does anyone how this could be achieved with the Entra ID External Identities plattform?